# Redirect /pages/pagename.php to index.php?url=pagename.php

Tags: .htaccess

I'm making a web application with PHP, but currently I'm stuck with something.

Here's an example of my page:
http://sitename.com/pages/pagename.php

But I want it to be:
http://sitename.com/index.php?url=pagename(.php) <-- so without the .php

I have tried the following `htaccess` code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine on<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)$ ./index.php?url=$1.php
```